# Not being able to run script with java jASN1 compiler

Tags: java, class, generator

after searching through net and this forum, and still being stuck at dead point, I finally decided to ask question here.
So basically I want to read from ASN1 binary files and parse it into CSV files. I found on this forum that there is Bouncy Castle library that handles ASN1 files, but it would be more convinient to map ASN1 files to Java classes.
So under one of the posts on this site, I found out that java class generator already exists, so I decided to try one from ASN Lab and followed their instructions on how to add and install their compiler into Eclipse, but then I realized that their software is not free.

So I tried to use this one openmcu's one and followed their user guide www.openmuc.org/asn1/user-guide/ , since it's free and I as I've seen it's still maintained. I followed these instructions and imported .jar files from directory
 **build/libs-all** into my Eclipse user libraries.

The next step they describe is running the script: 
**In a first step you have to compile the ASN.1 code of your choice to Java classes. To run the compiler you can use the
run scripts for Linux and Windows found in the run-scripts folder. Executing the scripts without any parameters will
print help information to the screen.**

But I don't get it how will my program work in the run-time, does this script has to be run from the java code?

I also looked here: https://github.com/juherr/jASN1/tree/master/sample, 
and I followed his instructions under README.txt file. So I tried to run the script from the command line just to see if it works:

```
**"C:\Users\a661517\Documents\RAdiation Project\jasn1-1.8.1\jasn1\run-scripts\jasn1-compiler.bat" -f x690BerExample.asn -o "generated/" -ns "generated"**
```

I am getting `**Error: Could not find or load main class Project\jasn1-1.8.1\jasn1\run-scripts\..\build\libs-all**`

I put EncodeDecodeSample.java class from his github page under /sample in libs-all folder and this java class has main function.

Sorry for any inconvenience and thank you in advance.

Comment: minor format errors

Comment: I manged to make it work. I had to use another tool for unzipping the compiler instead of WinRAR. Seems that generated classes do not have setters and getters, and I need to convert these classes back to csv files using BeanIO. For reading data I see that classes have decode method: [code]int decode(InputStream is, BerTag berTag)[/code], so I tried to get IS [code]Files.newInputStream(path)[/code] , but decode throws exception: http://textuploader.com/dog9a.